# What tool/process do I need to remove this bathroom exhaust fan from motor?

Tags: bathroom, tools, exhaust-fan, electric-motor

Bought a condo where exhaust fans weren't working with the plan to just replace the motors (both fans are identical). Found this replacement motor for the current JA2C463N motors (https://www.homeessentialsdirect.com/pennbarry-60030-0-1-80hp-115v-1400rpm-1spd-motor-60030-0/), [image] but figured I should be sure about how to remove the motor from an existing housing before actually buying the new motors. I realized then the mounting nuts connecting the motor to the housing are inaccessible while the fan itself is on (nuts a bit out of focus here, but you can see the problem). [image]

This is how the fan itself is secured to the motor. [image] [image] There is this small hole on the inner side as well; not sure how or if it comes into play. [image] Any thoughts?

Separate from this question, but also the new motors indicate same power/hp, but 1,400 rpm instead of original 1,200--any thoughts there?

Comment: The RPM may just be quoting loaded .vs. unloaded speed. *i.e.* motor speed *.vs.* motor with fan attached speed.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The "small hole on the inner side" is a set screw. You will see that it lines up with the flat surface milled into the side of the shaft. You must unscrew it with a hex wrench, aka an Allen wrench.

I don't know how you're meant to get the hex wrench into position. I would bend one of the fan blades if necessary.

Once the set screw is loosened, the fan will still be difficult to remove because of all the rust etc. A combination of prying, tapping, and cursing is usually required.

Comment: Just saw that small hole/set screw also. Good use of penetrating oil will probably help.  Raising the fan itself, by placing blocks around the mounting plate will help with the tapping it off.

Comment: Looked at it more closely now and yes, I understand. I have a long enough Allen key of the right size that you can actually just it slip through the blades to reach the set screw opening; unfortunately, I can't actually loosen the screw at all. Not how I hoped things to end up. I can find replacement motors, but having difficulty finding an entire replacement motor, fan, and mount that will fit with what is in the ceiling now. Had visions of this being an easier task than it seems it will be.

Comment: I will see if penetrating oil does the trick.

Comment: Heat and penetrating oil (NOT WD-40 - WD-40 is good at displacing water, and is NOT a penetrating oil - PB-Blaster, Kroil, Etc... Be a bit patient rather than amping up the torque until you strip the screw. All else fails, drill it out and re-tap a size larger.

Comment: Remember that it might turn out to be Torx or similar, or might be a metric key when you're expecting English. Apply penetrating oil, apply patience, apply BFI only if necessary.

Answer (score 2):

You'd need a big gear puller with a very small center shaft, and that might be hard to come by. As far as I know, these really aren't designed to be repaired (like so many items these days), but simply replaced in whole. I'd be happy to hear from others that prove this expectation wrong.

Your puller has to be big enough to grab the edges of the fan, but the center "punch" part (not sure of the technical name) has to be small enough to push against the motor shaft - the part at the very center of the 1" reinforcement at hub in the 4th picture.

If you can find a gear/puller fits the bill, you're likely to simply bend the fan instead of pulling it off. The fan is fairly thin stamped steel and isn't going to be all that resistant to the puller when you're lifting on the outer edge of the fan.

Answer (score 0):

Broan/NuTone made very popular QT100 and QT110 series exhaust fans, for which you can easily find replacement motors and/or "squirrel-cage" fan assemblies. I suspect that the only non-standard part in what you have is the square metal mounting bracket; as you note, if you can remove the squirrel-cage, you can get at the 4 mounting bolts for the motor.

I would measure your squirrel cage diameter and height and find an aftermarket motor/cage assembly that matched that and the motor rating, then destructively remove your squirrel cage (and motor), keeping only the metal mounting bracket. Remove the squirrel cage from your new motor/cage, mount the new motor to your metal bracket, remount the cage to the motor shaft, and you're good to go.

As you've probably already found by searching, your unit seems to be

> 60030A Penn Vent Motor (JA2C463N, 7163-9773) Zephyr ZT,1/80 hp 1400
> RPM,115V
>
> 115 Volts 60 Hz .74 Amps 1/80 HP 1400 RPM 5/16" x 1-9/16" Shaft

I would think an HVAC supply house should be able to hook you up with a replacement squirrel cage that will fit a motor with the above specs.